# Bing Maps REST Service Toolkit not working

Tags: rest, maps, bing-maps, bing, toolkit

I have downloaded Bing maps toolkit from GitHub site. Try to run it by adding my key, it throws an error, "There was an error deserializing the object of type BingMapsRESTToolkit.Response. Encountered unexpected character '<'.".

Please advise.

Comment: Use the NuGet package instead. It is designed to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

Download the NuGet package for the package, not the project itself.

The Bing Maps REST Services Toolkit is available as a NuGet package. If using Visual Studio, open the nuget package manager, select the Browse tab and search for "Bing Maps REST". This should reduce the list of results enough to find the "BingMapsRESTToolkit" package. The owner of the package is bingmaps and the author is Microsoft.
Alternatively, if you are using the nuget command line:

> PM> Install-Package BingMapsRESTToolkit

If you prefer to use the NuGet package manager interface, ere are the steps to add the Bing Maps REST toolkit to your project:

1. In Visual Studio select Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Managed Nuget Packages for Solution
2. Select Browse tab and search for "BingMapsRESTToolkit".
3. Select the top result from Microsoft.
4. Check the projects you want to add it to then press install.